# jQuery post - wait for response

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

i am using basic jQuery post requests in for cycle.

```
for (i = 1; i < 2; i++) {

     for (ii = 0; ii < 2; ii++) {

        $.post( "url", 'some data')
          .done(function( data ) {

            if(data.length > 2){
              $("#datagot").append(ii);
            }

        });
     }        


}
```

I need to pass the ii variable into the .done function, but the script does not wait till the request is completed, so the ii is not correct for each request.

How can i achieve that? Is there any way to pass ii as parameter, any ideas?

Comment: can u try always instead of done..

Answer (score 1):

I think this is wrong approach, from your code you are doing 2 post call for every ii from 0 to 2, so 0 and 1 so two ajax call, you need of the deferred object so a thing like this if they are asynchronous

```
$.when(callOne(),callTwo()).then(function(answerOne,answerTwo){
    if (answerOne == 'answerOneReturned' && answerTwo =='answerTwoReturned'){
        $("#datagot").append(answerOne);
         $("#datagot").append(answerTwo);
    }

});

function callOne(){
return $.ajax({
    url:'myUrl.php',
    type:'POST',
    dataType:'html'
    }).then(function(data) {
        if (data == 'something'){
             myAnswer = 'answerOneReturned';
        }

        return myAnswer;
    }); 
 }

function callTwo(){
return $.ajax({
    url:'myUrl.php',
    type:'POST',
    dataType:'html'
    }).then(function(data) {

        if (data == 'something'){
             myAnswerTwo = 'answerTwoReturned';
        }

        return myAnswerTwo;
    }); 
 }
```

The same functions above if they are synchronous but you must use this written for syncronous

```
$.when(callOne()).then(function(answerOne){
    if (answerOne== 'answerOneReturned'){
        return callTwo();
    }

}).then(function(answerTwo){
    if (answerTwo== 'answerTwoReturned'){
        //Do append
    }

});
```

Must precise that the deferred object allow to do, for example, 10 ajax call in asynchronous but handle all the answers and directing where you want...so if anwserOne is A and answerTwo is B do a thing in answerOne is C and answerTwo id D do another thing....etc..etc...

And sorry but this what means?

```
    for (i = 1; i < 2; i++) {
```

It's not necessary for i=1 and minor or 2 ?It's not necessary....

Answer (score 0):

No. The for loops are synchronous, meaning that at ii=0, $.post will run. As soon as $.post is run, ii=1 will occur and the $.post for that will run.

The .done for ii=0 could occur 2 minutes later and the .done for ii=1 could occur 1 minute before that, or vice versa, as an example. You cannot know *which* .done will occur first, or *when* they will occur.

To "know" which ii has finished inside of .done, you'll need to pass the value of ii in $.post data, and have it returned. Returning an array is an easy way to do this. For example:

```
.done(function( data ) {
   let dataii = data[0];
   let datagot = data[1];

   if(datagot.length > 2){
     $("#datagot").append(dataii);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two simple solutions:

1) Use `let ii = 0`. Since variables declared with `let` only exist in the context of the block in which they are declared, `ii` will be re-created for every iteration of the loop. Thus subsequent iterations of the loop will not change its value, but act on their own copies of `ii`:

```
for (let ii = 0; ii < 2; ii++) {
    ...
}
```

2) Use [partial application](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Partially_applied_functions). Just use [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to apply the first argument of the `done` handler:

```
$.post( "url", 'some data')
    .done(function(ii, data) {
        ...
    }.bind(null, ii)) // add this
```

This will effectively create a snapshot of the current value of `ii` at the time it is applied (bound) to the inner function.